# How to update changes in tomcat without restarting while site is live?

Tags: java, tomcat, production, mode

Is there any proper way to update changes in java class file on tomcat, while site is live,  without restarting tomcat ?

I know about reloadable attribute in context but is it reliable ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can directly replace the class files inside tomcat directory and rest of the things tomcat will manage itself.

**Note :** If changes in any class modifies the class structure ie: any new function, variable etc are introduced or any signature change, then it may lead to some trouble while class reloading .